# How do I apply calendar.monthcalendar function to return a matrix of days for an entire year instead of months by months manually?

Tags: python, loops, calendar

How could this be done through For loops?

```
import calendar

print(calendar.monthcalendar(2020,1))
print(calendar.monthcalendar(2020,2))
print(calendar.monthcalendar(2020,3))
print(calendar.monthcalendar(2020,4))
print(calendar.monthcalendar(2020,5))
print(calendar.monthcalendar(2020,6))
print(calendar.monthcalendar(2020,7))
print(calendar.monthcalendar(2020,8))
print(calendar.monthcalendar(2020,9))
print(calendar.monthcalendar(2020,10))
print(calendar.monthcalendar(2020,11))
print(calendar.monthcalendar(2020,12))
```

I am a complete beginner here, so sorry if this question seems really dumb:(

Answer (score 1):

```
import calendar

for i in range(1,13):
    print(calendar.monthcalendar(2020,i))
```